# Print JSON data from currencyconverterapi

Tags: php, json, currency

I'm trying to print the value from currency converter API JSON data.

Anyone can help me to print the value from this URL

https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_IDR&compact=y?

Comment: Iam Loki   check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) along with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

$json_data = file_get_contents('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_IDR&compact=y');

$array = json_decode($json_data, true);

var_dump($array["USD_IDR"]["val"]);

?>
```

I have tested it on the local machine and working fine:-

https://prnt.sc/jd1kxo  And https://prnt.sc/jd1l7w

Comment: Thanks @Alive to Die

Comment: @IamLoki  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$data = json_decode('{"USD_IDR":{"val":13965}}', TRUE);
var_dump($data["USD_IDR"]["val"]); //int(13965)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ob_start();
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_IDR&compact=y');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $jsontoarr = json_decode($response);

  echo $jsontoarr->USD_IDR->val;
```

Good luck.